# Base64 encoding or bin2hex random string

Tags: php, string, random, base64

When converting "random bytes" to a string, is there any difference as to whether I should use `base64_encode` or `bin2hex`?

```
$bytes = openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(32); // alternatively read from /dev/urandom

echo base64_encode($bytes); // some 44 character string
echo bin2hex($bytes); // some 64 character string
```

To use as a salt for `bcrypt`, obviously modified base64 is the correct choice because that is what's expected. But for contexts like account sign-up confirmation key or a unique non-sequential object identifier, which is the correct choice?

I am aware of the [`random_compat` library](https://github.com/ircmaxell/random_compat) but this is for learning purposes as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Besides length? Not really. They're both representations of the same data. The choice is up to you.

But keep in mind:

- Base64 data may include the characters `+`, `/`, and `=`, which may need to be URL encoded.
- As Base64 data may contain any alphanumeric character, there's a *slight* chance that it'll contain objectionable words. (This is also technically possible with hex-encoded data, but less common, as it only uses the letters A through F.)